# css check previous element classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

So, in my code i have the following possibilities:

```
<div class="price-box">
    <p class="was-old-price">$PRICE$</p>
    <p class="special-price">$PRICE$</p>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="price-box">
    <p class="old-price">$PRICE$</p>
    <p class="special-price">$PRICE$</p>
</div>
```

I want when `.was-old-price` get printed insted of `.old-price`, the `.special-price` has `display:none` properties. is this possible to achieve this using CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with the the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator (`+`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) selector:

```css
.was-old-price + .special-price {
    display: none;
}
```

The `E + F` selector selects the `F` element immediately following the `E` element. In this case, the `.special-price` element immediately following the `.was-old-price` element. Here's an example:

```css
.was-old-price + .special-price {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Box 1</h3>
<div class="price-box">
    <p class="was-old-price">was-old-price</p>
    <p class="special-price">special-price</p>
</div>

<h3>Box 2</h3>
<div class="price-box">
    <p class="old-price">old-price</p>
    <p class="special-price">special-price</p>
</div>
```

Comment: oh man, i was over thinking..i thought there was a way to check previous elements classes, just like `prev()` in jQuery. thanks for this. I am gonna accept this answer